# Syntax to search for datetime field in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, rest, elasticsearch, jhipster

What's the syntax to search for datetime field using a URI by providing request parameters in Elasticsearch? I'm using Jhipster, then I need to use a URI syntax.